# Post request with object and protocol with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, post, request, httpurlconnection

In my project I have to do an http post request to a server whit java and I'm using the class HttpURLConnection to do this.
I want to add the object and the protocol but i don't know how to do it.
The class has the method setRequestMethod and i can write something like this:

```
myConnection.setRequestMethod ("POST");
```

but my post requires something like this "POST hereThereIsTheObject HTTP/1.1".
How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you'll get with the code you posted. The `hereThereIsTheObject` part is the `URL` that you get the `HttpURLConnection` from.

If you want to send an *object* in that position, you can't. It isn't valid HTTP.